# linux commandline single quotes escape problem

Tags: bash

i want to echo content as following

```
GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'zabbix_agent'@927.0.0.1';
```

but `echo \\\0471` will get `9` ,I do want this ,how can I do ?

```
echo -e "GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO \\047zabbix_agent\\047@\\047127.0.0.1\\047;"
GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'zabbix_agent'@927.0.0.1';
```

Comment: this is a different thing ,actually ,the command is send by salt to execute on remote host.  the whole command is # salt 'yunpei_db1' cmd.run 'echo -e "create user \\047zabbix_agent\\047@\\047127.0.0.1\\047 identified by \\047password\\047;GRANT SELECT, PROCESS, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO \\047zabbix_agent\\047@\\047127.0.0.1\\047;" '   this command will create a local account on a remote mysql .

Comment: `927.0.0.1` this is a very strange ip address, I think you meant `127.0.0.1`

Comment: \\0471 -> 9.   what I want is  '1 ,not 9